# Forming conditional probabilities/densities from a continuous distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X\sim U[0,1]$. I am trying to understand how to derive probability/density of some realization $x \in [0,1]$ conditional on $x \in E\subseteq[0,1]$. The more I think about it, the more I seem to be confused. Any help would be welcome.

1) If $Pr(X\in E)>0$, the density seems to be $f_X(x|X \in E)=\frac{f_X(x)}{Pr(X\in E)} $. So for example we can calculate $f_X(x|X \leq 1/2)=\frac{f_X(x)}{1/2}=2f_X(x)=2 $.

So far so good. Now suppose that $Pr(X\in E)=0$.

2) For example $E=\{1/4, 3/4 \}$. It seems intuitive that the probability of $X=1/$4 is given by
$$
Pr(X=1/4|X \in E)=\frac{f_X(1/4)}{f_X(1/4)+f_X(3/4)}=1/2.
$$
Is this correct? It feels intuitive, but I am not convinced we can use densities in this way to obtain probabilities. If it is correct, can you point me to a more formal explanation of why it works? Also, is it true that for any finite $E$ it holds
$$
Pr(X=x|X \in E)=\frac{f_X(x)}{\sum_{y\in E} f_X(y)}?
$$

3) Now let $E= \{y \in [0,1]: y \in \mathbb{Q} \}$, i.e. $y$ is a rational number. There are infinitely many rational numbers in the unit interval. What is $Pr(X=x|X\in E)$? Intuition suggests that $Pr(X=x|X\in E)=0$. Also, proceeding as in 2) gives $\sum_{y\in E} f_X(y)=\infty$, so that $Pr(X=x|X\in E)=0$. If it is indeed true that $Pr(X=x|X\in E)=0$, would it be possible to calculate the conditional density of $X$, i.e. $f_X(x|X \in E)$? Approach as in 1) doesn't work since $Pr(X=x|X\in E)=0$.

Comment: These sorts of questions make a lot more sense when you phrase probability in terms  of measure theory.  A formal definition of conditional expectation in terms of the Radon Nikodym derivative can be seen at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you write $Pr(x|x\in E)$?

Comment: @zoli I wanted to express the conditional probability of $x$ given that the event $E$ has occurred. For example, let $E=\{ 1/4, 3/4\}$ as in 2). Suppose I tell you I drew a number from $U[0,1]$ and that I drew either $1/4$ or $3/4$. Then I ask you what is the probability that the number I drew is $1/4$.

Comment: @muaddib I agree with you - it is just that I am not that comfortable with measure theory, so I tried to pose the question in the language that is accessible to me. I guess understanding which parts of the question make little sense as posed would also help me understand the problem better. Also, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I can formulate an appetizer of an answer, but it really requires some sort of measure theory. Do you know about this subject?

Comment: @Conformal I am not very comfortable with it, but I am also not afraid to get my hands dirty.

Comment: @igor Where you wrote $\Pr(x\mid x\in E)$ you seem to have meant $\Pr(X=x\mid X\in E)$.  $X$ is the random variable while $x, y$ are values that variable can realise.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, that is what I meant. Thanks for the edits!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let $X$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. Your correct question is as follows: How to express in the language of probability the following intuitive clear question: "What is the probability that $X=\frac{1}{4}$ assuming that either $X=\frac{1}{2}$ or $X=\frac{1}{4}$?" And the intuitive clear answer: "$\frac{1}{2}.$"

---

The pdf, by definition is a function whose integral over an interval gives the probability of the event that the corresponding random variable falls in the set in question. So for instance

$$P(\frac{1}{2}\le X\le \frac{1}{2}+\Delta x )=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\Delta x}\ dx = \Delta x.$$

---

Your specific question can be formulated then the following way

$$P(\frac{1}{4}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x \mid \frac{1}{4}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x \cup \frac{1}{2}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x )=?$$

Based on the definition of the conditional probability we have 
$$\frac{P(\frac{1}{4}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x \cap \frac{1}{4}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x \cup \frac{1}{2}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x )}{P(\frac{1}{4}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x \cup \frac{1}{2}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x)}=?$$

If $\Delta x$ is small enough then the question is
 $$\frac{P(\frac{1}{4}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x)}{P(\frac{1}{4}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x)+P(\frac{1}{2}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x)}=?$$

---

Using the definition of the probability density we have

$$\frac{P(\frac{1}{4}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x)}{P(\frac{1}{4}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x)+P(\frac{1}{2}\le X<\frac{1}{4}+\Delta x)}=\frac{\Delta x}{2\Delta x}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

---

This argumentation can be generalized for the the case when $f_X$, the df of $X$ exists and when $E=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$, and $P(X\in E)>0)$, and $x_k \in E$ and $\Delta x$ is small enough then

$$P(x_k<X<x_k+\Delta x \mid X\in E)=\frac{P(x_k<X<x_k+\Delta x)}{\sum_{i=1}^n P(x_i<X<x_i+\Delta x)}=$$
$$\approx\frac{f(x_k)\Delta x}{ \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\Delta x}=\frac{f(x_k)}{ \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)}.$$

---

Now, what if $E$ is the set of rational numbers? If we assume the existence of the pdf then $P(X=q)=0$ for all rationals. (The countable sum of these zeros is also $0$.) So we cannot derive the conclusion above. (As it was observed by the OP.)

---

However, if we don't assume the existence of the pdf then we can have a similar result. Let $\{q_i\}$ is an ordered sequence of the rationals and let $p_i=P(X=q_i)$ such that $\sum p_i=1$.  Now if $E$ is a subset of rationals and $\sum_{q_i\in E}p_i>0$ then
$$P(X=x_k \mid X\in E)=\begin{cases}0,& \text{ if } x_k \notin E\\
\frac{p_k}{\sum_{x_i \in E}},& \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

The distribution over the rationals cannot be uniform. This is the speck on the face of  classical probability theory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using the exact approach that you used, one should also be able to prove that for any finite set $E$, the probability that $x=X$, given that $X \in E$ is given by $\frac{f(x)}{\sum_{y \in E}f(y)}$. I guess that makes sense.

Comment: @igor: Yes. And if you liked my answer then please hit the check mark button.

Comment: I would like to keep the question open a bit longer. Also, I am still waiting to see if somebody answers the part 3).

Comment: @igor: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $P(x \in E) = 0$, then the conditional density $f(x|x \in E)$ is undefined because it would involve division by zero.

One can even make up an example of this kind of situation for a discrete density. Suppose an
urn contains 2 red balls, 3 green balls, and no white balls.
You can find the conditional probability that the second
ball is green given that the first is red. But it doesn't
make sense to ask for the conditional probability that the
second ball is green given that the first is white.

In some bivariate cases (maybe later on in your course) you 
may have a jointly continuous density $f(x, y)$ and ask for
the conditional distribution $f(x|Y = y).$ Then $P(Y = y) = 0,$
but if you can interpret $f(x|Y = y)$ in terms of a limit
in which the denominator is $P[Y \in (y-\epsilon_1,y+\epsilon_2)],$
as $\epsilon_i \rightarrow 0,$ then the conditional distribution
may make sense. (The limit has to be unambiguous.)

Comment: The conditional density may be undefined - but I think we should be able to make some probabilistic statements. I agree that conditioning on a white ball in your example does not make sense. However, it seems a sensible question to ask whether you should bet a dollar to win three if a random number drawn from a $U[0,1]$, which I reveal to you is rational, is greater than $4/7$. (I am aware that I am not understand something completely here, but I would like to figure it out.)

Comment: In a real situation, how could you possibly know whether an number from $U[0,1]$ is rational? In practice, you have to round to some number of decimal places, and in effect you tell me what very small interval it is in. You could put some strange measure on the interval that assigns a positive value to all its rationals, but that could not possibly correspond to a real-life experiment.